# java: how to use clone() and what about the cast check

Tags: java, clone, compiler-warnings

This code:

```
class RawStringIterator {
        java.util.Stack<State> stateStack = new java.util.Stack<State>();
        RawStringIterator(RawStringIterator i) {
              stateStack = (java.util.Stack<State>) i.stateStack.clone();
        }
        /* ... */
}
```

gives me this warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to Stack<Utils.OperatorTree.RawStringIterator.State>
```

I guess I can ignore the warning here. But I wonder about how to use `clone()` in general? Do I always have to use a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` every time I use `clone()`? Or should I always do the completely redundant extra check?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have the choice, the best is not to implement / use `clone()` at all, because [it is a broken API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410035/how-to-make-a-copy-of-arraylist-object-which-is-type-of-list/3410133#3410133). Just implement / use a copy constructor instead.

If for some pressing reason you must use `clone()` but can change its implementation, consider declaring `Stack<T>.clone()` to return `Stack<T>` instead of `Object` - covariant return types are legal since Java5.

**Update:** if the `Stack` in question is `java.util.Stack`, consider [its Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html):

> A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the [`Deque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class.

And e.g. [`ArrayDeque`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) provides a [copy constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html#ArrayDeque%28java.util.Collection%29).

Comment: `Stack<T>` is `java.util.Stack<T>` here. So I cannot really change any declaration there.

Comment: @Albert, you may still be able to switch to a different collection though - see my update.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to avoid the cast here. `clone()` returns `Object`, if it is `java.util.Stack`, it is not making use of co-variant return types.

If this is not `java.util.Stack`, then don't implement `clone()` - it's really hard to get it right. Make a copy-constructor instead.

Comment: You can (and are recommended to) use covariant return types with your `clone()` - Effective Java 2nd Ed. Item 11 shows explicit examples.

Comment: yes, but java.util.Stack does not. That was my point. I'll clarify

Comment: No, `java.util.Stack` does not have a copy constructor. Otherwise I would have used it.

Answer (score 0):

You have very little choice but to ignore it.

Whilst not directly relevant (because you're not writing a `clone()` method), this entry in the [Java Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ502) makes good reading (as does the whole FAQ!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need to explicitly suppress the warnings each time you use `clone()`.

This is one of the reasons you might prefer to use copy constructors instead of `clone()`, if available.

By the way in your code, when the `RawStringIterator(RawStringIterator i)` constructor is used, the first initialisation of `stateStack` is unnecessary:

```
class RawStringIterator {
    Stack<State> stateStack = new Stack<State>();
    RawStringIterator(RawStringIterator i) {
          stateStack = (Stack<State>) i.stateStack.clone();
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

You might want to remove that.