# Make a deep copy with clone

Tags: java, list, clone

I am having a list of company objects. I am trying to clone this list with:

```
public static List<Company> cloneList(List<Company> list) {
    List<Company> clone = new ArrayList<Company>(list.size());
    for(Company item: list) clone.add(item.clone());
    return clone;
}
```

However my compiler says:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The method add(Company) in the type List<Company> is not applicable for the arguments 
     (Object)
```

Why is this not possible to make a deep copy with `clone()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `clone()` method is defined on the root class `Object` (see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)). It returns an Object, therefore, if you haven't changed its return type to the concrete class while overriding, you have to cast it to the proper type, e.g. :

```
clone.add((Company) item.clone());
```

or define `clone()` with a covariant return type in your class as:

```
public class Company implements Cloneable {
   // stuff ...

   public Company clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException { /* do clone */ }
}
```

Note that you **have** to override the clone method as it is defined with visibility protected.

> By convention, classes that implement this interface should override Object.clone (which is protected) with a public method. See Object.clone() for details on overriding this method. [[source]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html)

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941850/java-how-to-use-clone-and-what-about-the-cast-check) question for other options.

Comment: Thx for your answer! However my compiler now gives me back: `The method clone() from the type Object is not visible`

Comment: Thx for your answer! What would you put into `/* do clone */`?

Comment: Code that creates a copy of the object using super.clone and then replaces all references to mutable state, which may not be shared, with a copy of that state. This also applies to state that is transitively reachable. Implementing clone can get complex quickly. I would advise you to not use clone(). Use a copy constructor or copy factory instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because `item.clone()` is returning an Object.
You can typecast here. So try changing it to this:

`clone.add((Company)item.clone());`

Also, override clone in your Company class.
The most simple way of doing it would be this one.

```
public Object clone(){
   return super.clone();
}
```

But you may come up with some custom implementation too.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Now my compiler give me back: `The method clone() from the type Object is not visible`

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `cloning` and `genericity`.

In your case you simply need to cast your clone as so :

```
clone.add((Company)item.clone());
```

Also make sure you deep clone your objects by overrriding the `Object#clone` method (see [Object.clone()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) :

> Otherwise, this method creates a new instance of the class of this object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

Answer (score -1):

clone() is implemented by Object and returns an Object. Override clone() in your class OR cast your result to Company.

`clone.add((Company) item.clone());`