# Android Java multiple array initialization

Tags: java, android, initialization

When declaring and assigning primitives before loop everything works fine and could be different from each other later on

```
//example
double sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4;
sum1 = sum2 = sum3 = sum4 = 0;
//later each gets own value correctly
```

Is it possible to make oneliner for an array?

```
//example
double[][] compare, updated; // works as intended
compare = updated = new double[SIZE][]; // makes compare=updated
```

Problem with second line is that it ignores all following calculations for *updated* and takes values from *compare*.

Comment: You can do this with primitives, but not ```Object```. ```Object``` use reference and array in java is ```Object```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by "one-liner" you mean a single statement and writing `new double[]` once, yes you can do this:

```
    double[] arr1, arr2;
    arr1 = (arr2 = new double[10]).clone(); // this is the line
    arr1[0] = 10;
    System.out.println(arr2[0]); // 0.0
```

But it's not very readable. It gets even worse when you do this with more arrays:

```
arr1 = (arr2 = (arr3 = new double[10]).clone()).clone();
```

I suggest you still use multiple lines to do this.

Comment: Yeah, basically I meant single line statement. So, there are no other convinient way for multiple equal-sized arrays initialization, right?

Comment: @JayJayAbrams I don't think there is.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @Sweeper's answer, consider using the `Arrays.copyOf()` method, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15962949/4851565). Note that the [`copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(double[],%20int)) method is type-safe whereas the [`clone()` method isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3941850/4851565).

```
double[] a, b, c;
c = Arrays.copyOf((b = Arrays.copyOf((a = new double[10]), a.length)), b.length);
```

But again, I'll reiterate as @Sweeper does, that this code really smells and you should consider doing it in multiple lines. As Steve McConnell says in [Code Complete 2nd Ed.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670), [the Primary Technical Imperative of software is to manage complexity](https://megakemp.com/2008/10/07/mcconnells-primary-technical-imperative/) (i.e. make your code simple). This doesn't necessarily mean reducing the lines of code, but more to do with enabling people who read your code to understand what it does at a glance.

Comment: I didn't use `Arrays.copyOf` because I tried to recreate the "feel" of `a = b = c` as much as possible, making the array variables closer. But good answer anyway, +1.