# How to clone a container (f.e. ArrayList) *easily*? Is it wrong to use .clone()?

Tags: java, casting, arraylist, clone

My, perhaps naive, solution for cloning an ArrayList (Vector replacement) is

```
ArrayList<Double> alBis = (ArrayList<Double>) alOriginal.clone();
```

considering that because the array contains immutable Doubles, I don't need
to clone them, but only the container.

As clone() returns an Object I put there the cast, but then
-Xlint complains it is an unchecked cast.

So, what now?  Ignore it with supressWarnings? Create a new ArrayList
and copy the orginal elements with a compact for? Any library method similar to
Arrays.copyOf()?

I read [Unchecked cast warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509076/how-do-i-address-unchecked-cast-warnings) but the accepted way is incredible complex.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`clone()` has major flaws, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092540/accessing-clone-from-java-lang-object) for reference. Don't use it!

Instead, all standard Collections have copy constructors. Use them:

```
List<Double> original = // some list
List<Double> copy = new ArrayList<Double>(original);
```

**Reference:**

- [`ArrayList<E>(Collection)` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29)

Comment: "clone() has major flaws" Can you elaborate? I haven't noticed any in the answers to the linked question.

Comment: Read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch

Comment: When considering use of a clone versus a copy constructor, one needs to consider what should happen if the passed-in object is of a class derived from the expected class.  In the case of clone, the new object will be the same class as the original; in the case of a copy constructor, it will be of the expected class.  In some cases, one behavior will be correct and the other decidedly wrong, with different behavior required in different cases.

Comment: @supercat nonsense. You can't invoke clone() without knowing what class you are dealing with, because clone() is not backed by any interface (Cloneable is just a marker interface). With thqt same knowledge, you can choose the Copy constructor of the correct class.

Comment: and by the same logic (clone is not backed by any interface) using clone() also violates Effective Java Item 52: "Refer to objects by their interfaces"

Comment: @Sean: If an extensible class Foo supports cloning, and Bar which derives from foo also supports cloning, then a routine which accepts a Foo may try to clone it even if it's a Bar.  In many such cases, the new object produced by the cloning operation should be a Bar.  If what's needed is a Foo whose Foo-ish properties match those of the Bar, and whose Bar-specific properties are stripped out, a copy constructor might be appropriate, but otherwise I would suggest that a Clone should in 99.44% of cases return an object of the same actual type as the original.

Comment: @supercat a) yup, that's what they thought when they designed the clone mechanism. But the same people [are now telling us there is a flaw in the process](http://books.google.de/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=Override+clone+judiciously&source=bl&ots=yXLnMnp_P0&sig=CgOAr2K2b5khhXZN0zxi867Y_IQ&hl=en&ei=52plTdmuJqGH4gagqYHcBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDkQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=Override%20clone%20judiciously&f=false). b) in the context of the question there is no hierarchy. ArrayList should hardly ever be subclassed and it's parents don't support clone().

Answer (score 4):

> Is it wrong to use .clone()?

It should be avoided whenever possible. It is an obsolete, badly designed and [fundamentally broken API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410035/how-to-make-a-copy-of-arraylist-object-which-is-type-of-list/3410133#3410133). Better use the copy constructor as @Sean suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would recommend [Google guava-libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), and:

```
 ImmutableCollection<Double> copy = ImmutableList.copyOf(original);
```

And do not use JRE clone, because it sucks (if you want to know why, then read references).

**Reference:**

- **[Class ImmutableList](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html)**
- [**Effective Java**, chapter 3 item 10](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf)